# Enthalpy and Throttling of steam

Tags: thermodynamics

What happens to steam when it is throttled ? How come the enthalpy is conserved even if the saturated pressure and consequent temperature are both down ? Why is the need for MP,LP AND HP for heating purposes if all will preserve the enthalpy ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enthalpy is conserved because no heat transfer occurs, and no work is done.  The pressure drops across the throttle, and the saturation temperature is lower at the lower pressure.  However, as the pressure drops some of the liquid in the saturated steam vaporizes and increases the steam quality (i.e. vapor fraction).  The lower temperature, lower pressure, higher quality steam contains the same enthalpy as the original steam.

Comment: Does this change also change the latent heat of steam at different saturation pressures ?

Comment: Yes.  You can find the values in the ASME steam tables which will give you the enthalpy of the gas, the liquid, and the phase-change enthalpy at different pressures and temperatures.

Comment: Is steam quality and dryness fraction one and the same...?(1-the other)

Comment: Sorry, I've never heard of "dryness fraction" so I can't answer that one.